# Eneloop rechargable batteries for mouse?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

I have a Apple Mighty Mouse, and I want to use rechargeable batteries, but I read somewhere on such a device I should only use Eneloop rechargeable batteries as they hold a charge when the device is not in use.

Is this a correct statement? I don't understand how one battery can hold a charge when the device is not in use, and another one cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different types of batteries have different discharge rates when not in use due to a number of factors including type of battery, state of charge, charging current, ambient temperature and other factors (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge) for more on self discharge).

I previously confused ESR with self discharge, where ESR determines the maximum current the battery can provide. For more information on the [characteristics of rechargeable batteries](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva533/snva533.pdf).

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eneloop) on Eneloop batteries, they have a low discharge rate, making them better for items that are used infrequently.

Also below is a chart that was provided to me by a professor previously that shows some of the advantages/disadvantages of different types of batteries:

[image]

Comment: So would you say for things that are in use say 8 hours out of a 24 hour day (remote, mouse, etc) eneloop batteries would be recommended?

Comment: For items with that amount of use, I would think you wouldn't really see the effects of the ESR and the eneloop should be just fine.

Comment: You seem to be confusing ESR and self discharge, which are two quite different things.   Self discharge would be more of a parallel or shunt resistance - norton, not thevenin.  Series resistance only comes into play if something (like a load) is completing the circuit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton upon your advice I read more and believe that I have corrected my mistake. Thanks.